# Can an exception be null or undefined?

Tags: javascript

If I am catching an exception in JS, can the exception ever be null or undefined? I saw a null check like the one below and was wondering if the first check for `e` is really necessary. My subjective feeling tells me that e will always have a value.

```
try {
  /// any code here
} catch (e) {
if (e && e.data && e.data.errors) {
  console.error(e.data.errors)
}
```

I have searched the web but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, if you throw a *plain value*, rather than a `new Error`, that situation can occur:

```js
try {
  throw undefined;
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e, typeof e);
}


try {
  throw null;
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e, typeof e);
}
```

But this is very bad practice - better to wrap a thrown error in `new Error` (or another of the appropriate error constructors):

```js
try {
  throw new Error('error!');
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
  console.log(e.stack);
  console.log(e.name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the code throw a custom exception, for example:

```js
try {
  throw "this is a string exeption";
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

But also, it is possible to:

```js
try {
  throw undefined;
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}

try {
  throw null;
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Probably in the custom code a custom exception with fields data field is used, and therefore you want to be sure you are catching the right custom exception and not a normal JS exception